# Unknown lifecycle phase on Maven

Tags: java, windows, maven, javafx, project

I tried to re-run my maven project in another laptop with the exact same file. I compiled it with this command:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=id.tumbs.App
```

This works on the laptop I was doing the project for, while throwing out an error on another laptop. The error code is

```
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".mainClass=id.tumbs.App". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the
```

format : or :[:]:. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException

I tried everything from what the error link told me and nothing work. Any solution, please?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try specifying your main class in double quotes:

```sh
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="id.tumbs.App"
```

Similarly, you can use `-Dexec.args="arg0 arg1"` to pass arguments.

If you're on Windows, you need to apply quotes for exec.mainClass and exec.args:

```sh
mvn exec:java -D"exec.mainClass"="id.tumbs.App"
```

If you're doing this more frequently, you can add the parameters into the pom.xml like this:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>java</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <mainClass>id.tumbs.App</mainClass>
    <arguments>
      <argument>arg0</argument>
      <argument>arg1</argument>
    </arguments>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If you're interested in knowing more details about this, take a look at the [maven-exec-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html).

Comment: thanks for the part - if u are on Windows ... !

Comment: YOU SAVED ME A LOT! Thank you so much!!! I don't have idea about quote in windows usage

Comment: Nailed it, needed to quote exec.mainClass in addition to the 
 argument - not sure why you also quoted the equal sign in the middle, I didn't need to (Maven 3.8.4).

Comment: You saved me a lot of time with windows. Thank you